# How to pass a variable to bpy.app.handlers.game_post in game engine

Tags: python, game-engine

I'm adding a handler with `bpy.app.handlers.game_post.append(my_handler)` to execute some cleanup code at the end of a game.

My handler gets called when I exit the game, but I can't find a way to pass in a parameter. Using global variables doesn't work. I also tried `bge.logic.globalDict['my_variable']` but I can't access that from the post game handler either.

Comment: BPY doesn`t work with BGE, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Hmm, my code gets called by adding `bpy.app.handlers.game_post` when the game ends. But the global variables are not available to me. I'm running a little http server when the game starts to accept commands from an external process that tell blender what to do in the game engine (my purpose is to produce a visualization demo for an external application)

Comment: For the moment I've found that overriding the ESC key to call my code does work, I can see the bge.logic.globalDict from that code.

Comment: Interesting, can you provide some screenshot to illustrate us. I know that bpy doesn't work outside of blender and if you use standalone bge, any call to bpy will break the game but obviously if the game run from blender everything should work, Anyway i would like to know more of course if you can and have time to show.

Comment: You might be able to access bpy data from inside the bge (as long as the BGE runs embedded inside Blender). You can use that to modify the Blender data from within your game. (It will take effect after the game session ended).